# How can I add two CSS types into an embedded HTML echo command and also perform a form validation technique?

Tags: php, html, css

**Question one**

How can I make my echo html paragraphs bold? here is what I tried below `'text-align:center,font-weight: bold'`?

```
 echo "<div style='text-align:center,font-weight: bold'><p>Hello ". $_SESSION['username entered']."please enter the correct username or password for this login page.</p></div>";

 echo "<div style='text-align:center'><p>Hi, you left the form feilds blank, please your username/password.</p></div>";
```

**Question two**

When the user inputs a username such as "circle" into my form how can I get that random username the user entered and get it to display on the line of code `echo "<div style='text-align:center,font-weight: bold'><p>Hello ". $_SESSION['username entered']."please enter the correct username or password for this login page.</p></div>";` If I use the variable `username` this will tell the user the actual correct username for the form which I don't want.

[see how if I use "username" it will tell the user what the actual script user is? I want the original username they entered to be displayed for example, if I type in "hjhjhj" as the username where it says "test1" I want that random user to be displayed there please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ISbj.png)

PHP

```
    <?php
   session_start();

   //Selectional statement
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
       $user = $_POST["username"];
       $pass = $_POST["password"];
       //login aspect
       if($user != "" || $pass != ""){
           if($user=="test1"&&$pass=="test1"){
               $_SESSION['login'] = "OK";
               $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
               $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;

               header('Location: protected.php');    //Links with protected php file

           }else{  //If this codition is met output the below
               $_SESSION['login'] = "";
               echo "<div style='text-align:center,font-weight: bold'><p>Hello ". $_SESSION['username entered']."please enter the correct username or password for this login page.</p></div>";

           }
       }else{
         $_SESSION['login'] = "";
         echo "<div style='text-align:center'><p>Hi, you left the form feilds blank, please your username/password.</p></div>";
       }
   }
   ?>
```

HTML

```
         <!-- Form Input Part -->
         <form class="text-center" method="post">
            <div class="form-group w-50 mx-auto">
               <!-- First Name input section -->
               <label for="username">USERNAME:</label>
               <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="15" name="username" placeholder="Input your username.">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group w-50 mx-auto">
               <!-- Last Name input section -->
               <label for="password">PASSWORD:</label>
               <input type="password" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="15" name="password" placeholder="Input your password.">
            </div>
            <!-- Form Button Submission -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">
            Login
            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
            </button>
         </form>
      </div>
```

Thanks for the help in advance:)

Comment: I don't understand your second question, but for the style you can use a `<b>` tag, or fix your inline styles to `text-align:center; font-weight: bold` (semi-colon, not a comma).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I'll also update my post. :)

Comment: if I type in "hjhjhj" as the username where it says "test1" (shown in the screenshot  in the post ) I want that random user to be displayed there please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1:

As Phix suggested in the comments, simply change your inline style to

`text-align:center;font-weight: bold`

using the semicolon instead of the comma.

## Question 2:

It depends on how much random do you want to have, but if it's not importand, change

`$_SESSION['username entered']` to one of the following:

- `substr(md5(time()),0,7)`
- `substr(md5(rand(0, 3000)),0,7)`
- `substr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40)),0,7)`
- `"User".rand(0, 99999)`

*For example*

```
echo "<div style='text-align:center,font-weight: bold'><p>Hello ". "User".rand(0, 99999).", please enter the correct username or password for this login page.</p></div>";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post, for question two is that how it should be written?                `echo "<div style='text-align:center; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; text-transform: uppercase; color: red;'><p> Warning Alert: Hello ". ['"User".rand(0, 99999)']." please enter the correct username or password for this login page.</p></div>";` as the word "ARRAY" appears?  https://imgur.com/a/vdG5COw